# Check if a circle with certain coordinates exists in arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry

I have an arraylist of circles in my app.  Basically, I am drawing a game board made of hexagon tiles.  I want to draw circles on each of the corners of each of the tiles.  I store all the tiles in an array of Tile objects.  Each tile has an array of points that make up the tile.  So I basically loop through each tile and each corner of the tile.  My problem is that  most of the tiles share intersections.  Therefore, one circle is drawn for each tile that shares that intersection.  But I only want to draw one at each intersection.  What I need to do is check if a circle exists in the array with a specific set of coordinates.  If it does exist, don't draw the circle.  I am aware of ArrayList.contains(), but have no clue how I can use that for my purpose.  Any ideas?

```
for (int t = 0; t < tiles.length; t++) {

    //Loop through the vertices of the current tile
    for (int v = 0; v < tiles[t].vertices.length; v++) {
        final double x = tiles[t].vertices[v].x;
        final double y = tiles[t].vertices[v].y;
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //This if statement doesn't work because the arraylist contains shapes, not points!
            if(!highlightedVertices.contains(new Point((int)x, (int)y))){ 
                Circle cir = new Circle();                         
                cir.setFill(Color.web("rgba(255, 235, 138, .3)"));
                cir.setCenterX(x);
                cir.setCenterY(y);
                cir.setRadius(windowHeight * .025);
                highlightedVertices.add(cir);
                wrapperPane.getChildren().add(cir);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Inside or outside circles? because inside circles will never reach a corner of the hexagon

Comment: Outside.  The center of the circle is the same as the corner of the hexagon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more pondering, I realized that Sebastian's answer wouldn't work because there was an offset of 1 pixel at each "intersection".  The code below that I wrote worked perfectly.  I just looped through each circle in the arraylist and determined if they each contained the origin of the new circle.

```
    private boolean CircleExists(Point origin, ArrayList<Circle> circles){

        boolean output = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++){

            Circle cir = circles.get(i);
            if(cir.contains(origin.x, origin.y)){
                output = true;
            }

        }

        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Since 2 circles are identical if and only if they have the same center and radius, when you move the center, you actually have a different circle - so they should not be equal.  If the hexagon intersections are the possible centers, and you know the radii of all the circles, you could use @Sebastian's solution to check whether you already have created each circle.

Answer (score 1):

The `Circle` class you are using could implement the method `equals`, due the `Collection` class, in the method `contains(Object o)`, uses the logic:

```
(o == null ? e == null: o.equals(e));
```

Where `e` is a current object in the list and `o` is a object to compare.

So, your `Circle` class would be:

**Class Circle**

```
public class Circle {
    private double centerX; //Asumming is a double
    private double centerY; //Asumming is a double
    private double radius;

    // +getters and setters

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (o instance of Circle) {
            Circle paramCircle = (Circle) o;
            if (paramCircle.getCenterX() == this.centerX && paramCircle.getCenterY() == this.centerY && paramCircle.getRadius() == this.radius) {
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `instanceof` instead of `instance of`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, was a typo. Thanks